# HAProxy - Using ACL in Frontend with SSL-Termination

Tags: haproxy

I'm using HAProxy in front of nginx. HAProxy terminates the SSL-Connection and passes only static requests to nginx (png, jpg, etc.).

I don't know why, but there are some requests forwarded to nginx which are not static (example: file with name "blank.htm"). My configuration of HAProxy is:

```
frontend fe-safe
  bind 10.x.x.x.:443 ssl crl /etc/haproxy/ssl.pem
  mode http
  option httplog
  option http-tunnel

  acl use_nginx path_end .js .css .jpg
  use_backend be_nginx if use_nginx

  default_backend be_default

backend be_nginx
  server nginx1 127.0.0.1:5000
backend be_default
  server def1 x.x.x.x:80
```

I'm using version 1.5.4. I couldn't find the information that ACLs are not supported when SSL-Termination used. Maybe it's not?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, found the answer!
First: everything is working fine with path_end and SSL-Termination.

But, if I'm using the option 'http-tunnel', than there is only the first request processed. All subsequent requests are just [forwarded](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#option%20http-tunnel).